# Magento: path in search field

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

in my fresh Magento installation I have the path of the current site shown in the search field.

When I am in a product with the path 'kfz/optimar-redtopr-rt-s-4-2.html' I have 'kfz/optimar-redtopr-rt-s-4-2.html' in search field.

When I am in the cart, I have 'checkout/cart' in search field.

This is a re-installed Magento. In the first installation i had the same problem. Could it be a problem of my (dev) server or a problem within magento?

I tried different themes with the same result.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks for reading that!

Comment: I've got the same problem with 1.9.2 only in production :-(

Answer (score 1):

Check **template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml** in your theme. You should have the value attribute like this:

```
value="<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getEscapedQueryText() ?>"
```

Also check for typo's in that file (missing `"` or `'`, for example).

Comment: Looks good in my case.

Complete line:

<input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getQueryParamName() ?>" value="<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getEscapedQueryText() ?>" class="input-text" />